# Capybara or Jasmine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, jasmine

I need to write a test (in Rails) that just shows a function was called. I am not sure to approach this in Jasmine or in Capybara?

My click event is:

```
<button class="player_vs_cpu_intro" onclick="playerVsCpu()">Player Vs. CPU's Selection</button>
```

My function is:

```
function playerVsCpu() {

    alert("Hello World");

  //other code is in here as well
}
```

Also, if I had a function within playerVsCpu();, can I test that as well?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jasmine for that. To check if a function has been called you need to use `spyOn()`.

```
describe("button click", function() {
    var btn;
    beforeEach(function() {
        btn = $('.player_vs_cpu_intro')[0];
    });
    it("should call playerVsCpu", function() {
        spyOn(window, 'playerVsCpu');
        $(btn).click();
        expect(window.playerVsCpu).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

You can also test if a function has been called inside playerVsCpu(). Let's say you call a function `anotherFunction()` inside `playerVsCpu()` and you want to assert that.

```
describe("playerVsCpu", function() {
    it("should call anotherFunction", function() {
        spyOn(window, 'anotherFunction');
        playerVsCpu();
        expect(window.anotherFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```